# Leek code question: 1. Two Sum. My python code makes sense but does not work on a specific variable

Tags: python

#Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
#You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
#You can return the answer in any order.

```
array = [1,6,3,4]
target = 5


def twosum(array, target):

    for n in array:
        list = array
        list.remove(n)
        for count in range(len(list)):
            if n + list[count] == target:
                print(f'The numbers to hit {target} are {n} and {list[count]}')
                array.remove(list[count])


twosum(array, target)
```

Hi, the output of this code provides me with the numbers from the array required to hit the target variable.

However, when I change my target = 10, it does not give 6 and 4. I have spent some time over this and still can't figure out why target = 10 does not work on this code.

If someone could explain the reason why it does not return 6 and 4, that will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your function does not return *anything*, it only prints.

Comment: `list = array.copy()`; if you don't do a copy both variables point to the same object, which will mess with your iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will remove from `array` when you remove something from `list`.

Change `list = array` to `list = array.copy()` and it should work.

Comment: Would also recommend to not use `list` as variable name since it overwrites the internal `list` function use `list_` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [1,6,3,4]
target = 10


def twosum(array, target):

    for n in array:
        #firstly DONOT use list as a variable as list is a keyword
        # i have changed your variable name to list_var
        list_var = array.copy() #secondly list_var=array is not good because
 #that means that if we change list_var then array will also change,
 #hence we #need to do copy() to ensure that new variable is created
        list_var.remove(n)
        for count in range(len(list_var)):
            if n + list_var[count] == target:
                print(f'The numbers to hit {target} are {n} and {list_var[count]}')
                array.remove(list_var[count])


twosum(array, target)
~
```